# Restore SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, restore

Using VB.NET, I want to restore a SQL Server database from a `.BAK` file without the "log file".

I tried using:

```vb
Restore database dbName 
from disk = '" & path & "'"
```

but it didn't work, exception that refers to

> ```
> "not finding _log file"
> ```

more specifically:

> ```
> Cannot open backup device 'D:\AlomohasebSQL.bak'.  
> Operating system error 2(‏‏Invalid path).  
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1  
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

From the more complete error message:

> Cannot open backup device 'D:\AlomohasebSQL.bak'. Operating system error 2 (‏‏Invalid path). Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Do you know the exact SQL restore statement you are performing? No matter what front-end language you are using, it should be executing something like this against the SQL Server:

```
RESTORE DATABASE myDatabaseName
FROM FILE = 'D:\myDatabaseBackup.BAK'
WITH (various options here)
```

In your case, I think the error message indicates that the backup file location ("D:\AlomohasebSQL.bak" in your error above) is incorrect. Obviously, make sure this is a valid drive, path and filename.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: This path needs to be visible *to the SQL Server*, not to wherever you are running this app. (Thanks @ColinMackay for bringing this up). In a related note, check to see that the **SQL Server service account** has the proper permissions to read this file at that location.

There is a (smaller) possibility that it doesn't know where to place the database files after it restores them. SQL does have a "default" path, but this is sometimes out of date. If necessary you can specify the path to restore the files to:

```
RESTORE DATABASE myDatabaseName
FROM FILE = 'D:\myDatabaseBackup.BAK'
WITH MOVE 'primarydatafilename' To 'D:\DB\data.mdf', 
     MOVE 'logfilename' To 'D:\DB\log.ldf'
```

You'd obviously need to know the files that are part of that database. If you don't, just use the SSMS restore wizard. There are ways to find that via the `RESTORE` command, let me know if you need that.

Comment: @BradC, Body thank you so so so so much, Finally, this is exactly what I want, It seems that I have to extract the ldf and mdf from the bak and move them to the original path

Answer (score -3):

In SQL, the LOG_TRANSACTION file is an undissolvable part of database - once you have defined that in your backup routine.

To get the restore without the LOG, you *must* define the backup as SIMPLE-FULL one, like below:

[image: The Task-Backup screen]

BUT, to get success on this, the database properties *must* also define that characteristics:

[image: The Database Properties screen]

Comment: This answer is incorrect. **ALL** SQL server databases need a log file, no matter what recovery mode you are in.